# Exclude certain assets from pipeline in development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets, sprockets

I would like to somehow prevent certain assets from being included in the asset pipeline in the development environment.

So far, I have tried the following:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
<% if Rails.env.production? %>
//= require google_analytics_snippet
<% end %>
```

and

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb    
<% if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production' %>
//= require google_analytics_snippet
<% end %>
```

All I seem to be achieving is whether or not the `//= require google_analytics_snippet` line appears in the manifest. The actual code in the google_analytics_snippet.js file is never loaded, regardless of environment when I use either of these attempted solutions.

Is there a way I can do this?

**Edit:**
I was using a javascript file called olark.js in my examples when I first posted this question. That was a bad choice of example since [Olark](http://www.olark.com/) has a rubygem which may solve the problem. I have changed the example because I am looking for the general form solution.

Comment: Do you have anything gemmed in your gemfile for olark? Are you only depending on the olark.js file for including this in your app?

Comment: I'm not using the Gem. All I'm using for Olark is the JS snippet. Anyway, I didn't want the question to be about Olark specifically. I'm looking for a more abstract solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've looked through the source of the sprockets and I found, 
that the directive preprocessor always runs before any engine. 
So, it's not possible to add any conditional logic into the directives section with ERB or other engine.

- https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/environment.rb#L51
- https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/processing.rb#L36
- https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/context.rb#L174

**UPDATE**

Joshua Peek, [answered](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/265#issuecomment-3187436) on my question:

> The answer is yes, but if this is what you are trying to do:
>
> ```
> <% if Rails.env.production? %> 
> //= require google_analytics_snippet
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> try this instead:
>
> ```
> <% if Rails.env.production?
> require_asset "google_analytics_snippet"
> end %>
> ```

Comment: Its very important to tell that the file should be called application.js.erb or the sintax is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your deployment environment you might look at the [rack/olark gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/rack-olark).

You could then probably try something like this in your gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rack-olark'
end
```

Just a thought..

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a more general solution. Olark was just meant to be an example. I've edited the question.